# Creating a fake user in Symfony2 for testing purposes

Tags: php, testing, symfony, phpunit

I'm somewhat new to testing in PHP. I've done quite a bit of testing on Rails using Cucumber, RSpec, Capybara and Factory Girl, but I've barely done any testing with PHP.

I'll ask a question about my current challenge in the most general way possible, since I've gone down a few specific paths and been met only with frustration.

**I want to write a functional test for signing a user in. What's a good way to create the test user object that I would need in order to try to sign in?**

Even more generally, what's the de facto standard for creating test objects in Symfony2? Fixtures? Some kind of factory?

In Ruby, I would use Factory Girl, since it lets you handle any object's dependencies in a clean, DRY way. There seems to be a Factory Girl equivalent in PHP in Phactory, but unfortunately it seems that that tool is not widely used and no longer maintained.

Comment: Three answers, scoring 0, -1 and -1. It looks to me so far like maybe there is no de facto standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Fixtures](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html) on a [test environment configuration](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html#testing-configuration)  are probably the way to go!

About the [fixtures being application-wide comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13255597/807239), I disagree.

If you were unit testing, maybe that would make a lot of sense.

[Functional tests](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html#functional-tests), however, are supposed to be application-wide.

Comment: Functional tests are supposed to be end-to-end — not application-wide.

Comment: Functional tests, as the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html#functional-tests) shoutout, "check the integration of the different layers of an application (from the routing to the views)". A single feature (with an *end-to-end* flow, can easily be considered an application. In that sense, anything with with a request and a response involved is an application. Thus, features can be considered application-wide. As well as functional tests.

Comment: End-to-end means a vertical slice from views to the database; application-wide means a horizontal slice that can have several vertical slices.

Comment: One test may need only one user, while another test may need 10 users and 20 articles. Populating the whole fixtures for each test is an overkill. Oh, and I hope you didn't mean to load fixtures once for the whole test suite — that's a very bad idea because tests are not isolated in that case. That's like Testing 101.

Comment: @DanielRibeiro, why do you say "probably" the way to go? Are fixtures what you use yourself?

Comment: Yes, I do use fixtures just like I said you should. They solve the problem you are trying to solve — and there is no need for you to write any more code than you should.

Comment: I'm picking this as the best answer since fixtures seem to be the closest thing to a de-facto standard for test objects. I think a builder/factory would be better, but I was asking for the *standard* way, not necessarily the *best* way. The application-wide debate is not of that much concern to me.

Answer (score 0):

I just write [test data builders](http://nat.truemesh.com/archives/000714.html) myself, because there is almost no boilerplate anyway. BTW, Factory Girl is an implementation of that very pattern.

You can find a good discussion of the pattern and a lot of other useful stuff in the [Growing Object-Oriented Software, Guided by Tests](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321503627) book.

And I recommend against fixtures, because they are application-wide. Each test better prepare only the data it needs for itself.

Comment: You had to write something from scratch? There's nothing usable out there already?

Comment: I couldn't find anything existing that's not coupled to a database. I needed something that builds just object that I could persist via my layer of managers like `UserManager`, `OrganizationManager` and so on. It wasn't that hard to write a builder for each of my model classes — nothing fancy.

Answer (score 0):

I use fixtures for functional tests but i disagree that they are application wide only. Im using it bundle-wide, defined in proper dirs in bundles. On test setup i run console fixtures:load method from proper directory and maybe not best solution but it works good for me. If anyone have better solution i would happily read about it :)